# Blocking Google Fonts in wordpress website

Tags: themes, fonts

I'm buliding a wordpress website for a work project. Our systems block access to the internet, so every function that tries to ping a link or an IP that isn't inside our system is blocked and slowing down the loading of the website.
Using the Inspect option in Chrome I've found out that Open Sans Google font is what slowing down my website:
[image]

How can I disable this font? I've tried changing themes and disabling different plugins, nothing worked.
Thanks!

Comment: there's not enough information here, is this in the default theme? Themes can add fonts in many ways, and some default themes used to use google fonts but newer versions switch to locally hosted fonts instead. This isn't something that can be solved with just what you've shared

Answer (score 0):

If you check your source code and look for "fonts." you will find a line that is calling the stylesheet. This could be "googleapis.com" or "google.com or other URL. Here's how mine looks (using Astra theme);

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='astra-google-fonts-css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%3A400%2C&#038;display=fallback&#038;ver=4.0.2' media='all' />
```

Make note of the ID (**astra-google-fonts-css**) and then add the following to your functions file;

```
function remove_google_fonts() {  
    wp_dequeue_style( 'astra-google-fonts' ); // do not include the "-css" part
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_google_fonts', 999 );
```

As you'll see above, I now reference the ID but leave off the "**-css**" part from the stylesheet ID.

Of course, it's best to edit the theme and not call the fonts to begin with, but this should help with the call out reference.

Comment: Actually better to make a Child Theme and then put that function in the Child Theme's functions.php . Any changes you make to a theme will be overwritten when the theme updates; and then your site has the same problem.

There are several plugins that will create a Child Theme from your active theme. I like the "Child Theme Wizard", but there are others. And lots of googles/bings/ducks to help you learn about Child Themes.

Comment: Yup. I always forget that people don't necessarily use child themes. It should be a requirement! :)